# MVC Multi Tennat Application how to add sub site

Tags: model-view-controller, multi-tenant

I have an intranet application for which the URL is as follows

http:\\ServerName]\RunLog\

I am adding another department/tenant/group of users which will utilize the same instance of the application and same database. Their data will be different from the existing users.  I am planning to add new column foreign key in each table to identify the specific tenant.  I authenticate users windows authentication.  I am thinking that the access to the application will be as follows

http:\[ServerName]\Platform1\RunLog

http:\[ServerName]\Platform2\RunLog

So for the above URL, how could I go about achieving that in the Application? I know how to make the table changes in SQL server, Updating the Entities, Updating the linq code in the controllers to pull up respective tennant data.  Any help to get me started would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly note that as you have given in your post, it is possible to identify the tenant's based on their URL. The table that contains the tenant details will also contain their url. So you will identify the tenant based on the URL. After identifying the tenant, we can authenticate the user's using the found tenant id / tenant code, get the tenant's configuration or settings using the same tenant id / tenant code.

I hope that you could have all the other entities of the application with a column called as `TenantId`. This will help you to fetch the data based on tenant. Your only change will be in the data access layer where you will filter the data that you retrieve from the Database.

Let me know if you have any other clarifications regarding the other specifics of this implementation.